# How to convert the contents in the Stacklayout to Pdf or png form in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, image, pdf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want convert the contents in the StackLayout to .png or .pdf format and need to print the same from my iOS device. And my printer will support only image and pdf. How can I achieve this in xamarin forms.Please help me. Here is my Xaml.

```
<StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Frame HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray"
               CornerRadius="0" VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="30">
                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                 <Label.FormattedText>
                     <FormattedString>
                         <Span Text="ID : " FontAttributes="Bold"
                               TextColor="Black"/>
                         <Span Text="1234" TextColor="Green" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                     </FormattedString>
                 </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
                <Frame CornerRadius="1" BorderColor="Green"
                       HasShadow="False" WidthRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Source="ProfileImg" HeightRequest="70"
                           WidthRequest="50"/>
                </Frame>
                <Label Text="Xamarin" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="40" TextColor="Black"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            
                <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="Phone No : " TextColor="Gray" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            <Span Text="1234567890" TextColor="Green" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                        </FormattedString>
                   </Label.FormattedText>
               </Label>
           </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Xamarin Essentials has a screenshot function

Comment: @Jason , but I don't need the blank space only needs contents in that  frame, when taking screenshot it will include the blank space also

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could do that. You could make it by using **ImageFromXamarinUI** Nuget. Let me give you an example:

In the xaml file, set a name for the frame you want to capture. Let's call it "myfame":

```
<Frame x:Name="myframe"    HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray"
               CornerRadius="0" VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center">
```

In the .cs file, first use the new Nuget:

```
using ImageFromXamarinUI;
```

Then use the following code:

```
async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var imgStream = await myframe.CaptureImageAsync(); // take the content of myframe as a screenshot
        
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "mypic.png");

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            imgStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

In iOS, you could find the png through Files App.

You should also set **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** key and **Application supports iTunes sharing** key to **Yes**.

In this way, you could capture any visual element to screenshot and save it to a png file.

===================origin post===============

As @Jason said, you could use [Xamarin.Essentials: Screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms). Try the following code:

```
    async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)  // i save the png when tapping the frame
    {
        var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync();
        var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync();

        string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "mypic.png");

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        } 
    }
```

In iOS, you could find the png through Files App.

You should also set **LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace** key and **Application supports iTunes sharing** key to **Yes**.

For more information, you could refer to [Xamarin.Essentials: Screenshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms) and [File system access in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system)

Hope it works for you.

Comment: but I don't need the blank space only needs contents in that frame, when taking screenshot it will include the blank space also

Comment: I have updated my answer. you could use ImageFromXamarinUI nuget and in this way you could capture visual element to a partial screenshot. Please have a try

Comment: You could take a partial screenshot of any visual element in forms and no need to write platform code in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this using Dependency service.

in iOS added the below code and convert the byte[] to imagesource from contentpage.cs.

```
 public byte[] LayoutToImage()
    {
        var view = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
       UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(view.Frame.Size);
        view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Frame, true);
        var image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
       using (var imageData = image.AsPNG())
        {
            var bytes = new byte[imageData.Length];
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
            return bytes;
        }
```